# Building projects on mac fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, asp.net-mvc-5, msbuild, visual-studio-mac

Some background first:

In my R&D team at work we have some web projects that were written in .NET MVC 5. We also have some projects that are running on our dev machines in python (with pycharm).

Basically we work with Macs for development, but since the production servers are building the projects on windows we also work with VM running Windows 10 (with the parallels program).

So when I'm developing (I'm a web developer. Mainly client but doing some server sometimes), I'm running 2 pyhton projects, local db, local elastic search, and a Windows 10 VM with visual studio 2017 for the MVC and webstorm for client development.

This is far from ideal for me since I have a good machine that should allow great performance, but practically it doesn't work that fast.

So I tried building our solution with Rider for mac and with visual studio for mac, but if fails with the same error :

```
"/Users/dvir/projects/S6/web-dashboard/packages/RazorGenerator.MsBuild.2.2.6/build/RazorGenerator.MsBuild.targets(9,9): Error: InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."
```

Full error stack is:

```
"/Users/dvir/projects/Shift6/web-dashboard/packages/RazorGenerator.MsBuild.2.2.6/build/RazorGenerator.MsBuild.targets(9,9): Error: InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.MapPathFromMapper (System.String virtualPath) [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/WebConfigurationHost.cs:275 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.MapPath (System.String virtualPath) [0x00024] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/WebConfigurationHost.cs:232 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationHost.GetStreamName (System.String configPath) [0x00061] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/WebConfigurationHost.cs:148 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.Init (System.Configuration.Internal.IConfigSystem system, System.String configPath, System.Configuration.Configuration parent) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:127 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x00056] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:96 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:91 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:91 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:91 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration..ctor (System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem system, System.String locationSubPath) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/Configuration.cs:91 
  at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationFactory.Create (System.Type typeConfigHost, System.Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Configuration/System.Configuration/InternalConfigurationFactory.cs:41 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration (System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationFileMap fileMap, System.String path) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Configuration_2.0/WebConfigurationManager.cs:275 
  at RazorGenerator.Core.MvcWebConfigTransformer.Initialize (RazorGenerator.Core.RazorHost razorHost, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] directives) [0x000a2] in <743fc9a5bb9c4653a158bfeee3353916>:0 
  at RazorGenerator.Core.AggregateCodeTransformer.Initialize (RazorGenerator.Core.RazorHost razorHost, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] directives) [0x00015] in <743fc9a5bb9c4653a158bfeee3353916>:0 
  at RazorGenerator.Core.MvcViewTransformer.Initialize (RazorGenerator.Core.RazorHost razorHost, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] directives) [0x00000] in <743fc9a5bb9c4653a158bfeee3353916>:0 
  at RazorGenerator.Core.RazorCodeTransformerBase.RazorGenerator.Core.IRazorCodeTransformer.Initialize (RazorGenerator.Core.IRazorHost razorHost, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] directives) [0x00000] in <743fc9a5bb9c4653a158bfeee3353916>:0 
  at RazorGenerator.Core.RazorHost.GenerateCode () [0x00000] in <743fc9a5bb9c4653a158bfeee3353916>:0 
  at RazorGenerator.MsBuild.RazorCodeGen.ExecuteCore () [0x00166] in <0ed6243610554ecd93f4e898274cb949>:0 
 (Shift6.Dashboard)
```

The error points to line 21 of the following file:
(the one starting with the RazorCodeGen tag)

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RazorGeneratorMsBuildPath Condition=" '$(RazorGeneratorMsBuildPath)' == '' ">$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\tools\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.dll</RazorGeneratorMsBuildPath>
        <RazorViewsCodeGenDirectory Condition=" '$(RazorViewsCodeGenDirectory)' == '' ">$(MsBuildProjectDirectory)\obj\CodeGen\</RazorViewsCodeGenDirectory>

        <CompileDependsOn>
            PrecompileRazorFiles;
            $(CompileDependsOn);
        </CompileDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <RazorSrcFiles Condition=" '@(RazorSrcFiles)' == '' " Include="**\*.cshtml" />
        <RazorOutputFiles Include="@(RazorSrcFiles -> '$(RazorViewsCodeGenDirectory)%(RelativeDir)%(Filename)%(Extension).cs')" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(RazorGeneratorMsBuildPath)" TaskName="RazorCodeGen" />
    <Target Name="PrecompileRazorFiles"
                    Inputs="@(RazorSrcFiles)"
                    Outputs="@(RazorOutputFiles)">
        <RazorCodeGen ProjectRoot="$(MsBuildProjectDirectory)"
                                    FilesToPrecompile="@(RazorSrcFiles)"
                                    CodeGenDirectory="$(RazorViewsCodeGenDirectory)"
                                    RootNamespace="$(RootNamespace)">
            <Output TaskParameter="GeneratedFiles" ItemName="FilesGenerated" />
        </RazorCodeGen>
        <ItemGroup>
          <Compile Include="@(FilesGenerated)" Condition=" '@(RazorOutputFiles)' == '' "/>
          <Compile Include="@(RazorOutputFiles)" />
        </ItemGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

I can also post the build log later if needed.

Comment: Instead of betting your luck on that, switch to ASP.NET Core, which is fully supported on Mac.